# Incremental or background compilation for Maven/Gradle projects

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, sbt

I wonder if there are plugins/approaches for background/incremental compilation on the fly for Java/Android projects based on Maven or Gradle. For example, analogous of triggered execution from SBT `~compile`. Or if there any way to tell build system to recompile only changed files. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle doesn't currently offer incremental and/or continuous compilation for Java. Both  features are planned though, and although I don't have a concrete timeline to share, chances are that they will be delivered rather soon.

PS: It can pay off to split up larger codebases into multiple compile tasks, source sets, or projects, so that up-to-date checks and parallel execution can kick in.